# How to remove extra data in my CSV Export?

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, core-data

This is for my `iOS` app using `Core Data`.

I'm getting some extra information in my CSV export that I'd like to remove. Below is my code and an example of what I am seeing.

**Code:**

```
    NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToMemory];
    CHCSVWriter *writer = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithOutputStream:stream encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding delimiter:','];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Notes"];
    self.fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    for (NSString *instance in self.fetchedObjects) {
        [writer writeLineOfFields:@[instance.description]];
    }

    [writer closeStream];

    NSData *buffer = [stream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
    NSString * csvPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydata.csv"];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController * mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [[mailView navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [mailView setSubject:@"My Subject Line"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:csvPath]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:csvPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        }

        BOOL res = [[output dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:csvPath atomically:NO];

        if (!res) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Creating CSV" message:@"Check your permissions to make sure this app can create files so you may email the app data" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        } else{
            NSLog(@"Data saved! File path = %@", csvPath);
            [mailView addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:csvPath] mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"mydata.csv"];
            [self presentViewController:mailView animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

    } else {
        UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Error" message:@"Your device is not configured to send mail." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
```

**Output Example:**

```
<Notes: 0x1c009fb30> (entity: Notes; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://597EDC54-FFDE-43FA-8C61-DE67763C1D13/Notes/p2> ; data: {
    // My data shows here.
})
```

**What I want:**

I just want the saved data from the user input. Not the extra data about the entity, id, etc.

**Also:**

My data does not load in the email initially. I have to go into my `UIViewController` and then when I go to my Settings page and send the email the data shows. What would cause this?

Comment: It looks like the writer you are using takes an array and writes each element as a field. You should build an array of strings that holds the values you want and use that rather than `description`. Any properties that aren't already strings will of course need conversion. For any relationships you should grab the property from the relationship you want used in the CSV file. (like if the `Notes` entity has a `category` relationship and those entities have a `name` property you would use `instance.category.name` rather than `instance.category`.)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that result because you're relying the `description` method to get information about your objects. That method produces a string, and the string is what you're seeing-- something that's not CSV, or easy to convert to CSV.

I'm not familiar with CHCSVParser but it looks like you might want to override `description` in your `Notes` class to produce something that CHCSVParser can handle. The default implementation on `NSManagedObject`-- which is what you're using now-- is not a good choice for this situation.